# MySQL TimeStamp +5 Hours

Tags: mysql, time

I have a timestamp column in my mysql table. It is storing timestamps according to UTC/GMT. Now i wish it to store in IST format which is +5 hours than UTC/GMT.

What would be the query to do that?

Comment: You can set the offset for your server, check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html).

Comment: yes i can. but i need to do it with the query.

Comment: you should refer this link to different type of timpstamp:(http://chandlerdba.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/systimestamp-interval-processing/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DATE_ADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) in the select/where statement (up to your needs)... I think that's what you want.

```
DATE_ADD(date_column_name, INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select convert_tz(now(),'GMT','IST');
```

also

```
SELECT NOW()+INTERVAL 5 HOUR;
```

For more info [look here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14062)

Answer (score 0):

**try this variety of conversation for the time stamp as following as:**

```
SELECT NOW()+INTERVAL 5 HOUR;

SELECT DATE(COLUMN NAME)+INTERVAL 5 HOUR FROM t1(TABLANAME);

SELECT CONVERT_TZ(DATE(COLUMN NAME),'+1:00','+00:00') FROM t1(TABLANAME);

SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+1:00','+00:00');

SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','+1:00','+00:00');
```

refer this link in (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-date-time-functions.htm#function_convert-tz)